# What is an efficient "contains this element" list?

Tags: java

Ok, here's my problem: I download a list of items from the net and I store them in a db.
Across successive downloads an item could not be present anymore so, for example:

first download:
item1
item2
item3

second download:
item1
item3

in this case I have to detect that item2 is not present anymore and so remove it from the database also.

I thought to mantain a list of db items and call on it "contains" method for each item I download...but I'd like to do this in the most efficient way so I'm asking what of the many java implementations is the best for my problem.
Note that each item has an unique id, so the list would contain just strings.

Comment: If the end goal of detecting is just to remove it from the DB then why can't you just delete all existing values from DB and insert the new ones? This is much simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...in the most efficient way...

**Use the database.**

why don't you use a timestamp in your database?

When you download the new items, you probably have to update the database anyway (if some attributes changed), so you could also update the timestamp of all *newly* downloaded items.

After that you can delete all items out of your database whose timestamp are older than the download. So there is no need to have the complete old and new set in memory and do lookups, let the database handle that (It can do it much more efficient).

The overhead of saving the timestamp is minimal, you could even use something like a number that get incremented once every time your routine runs.

Answer (score 7):

A [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) has much better lookup performance than a List.
(If you need to retain the insertion order, use [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) instead.)

Comment: When changing from a `List` to a `HashSet` it might be worth noting that it doesn't care about the order of items in it.

Comment: Exactly. If order is important, use LinkedHashSet.

Answer (score 2):

If your downloads do not appear multiple times, I'd suggest you use a `HashSet`. If you plan to use objects later be sure that those objects override the `hashcode` method.